# How to run Superset in development mode

Tags: apache-superset

I want to run [Apache Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) in development mode. I have followed the [Guide](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) but unable to run the project properly. The problem I am facing is that the CSS files are not properly build.

Note: [Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) used to be named Caravel, and Panoramix in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved due to incompatible version of node due to which yarn was unable to fetch dependencies.

Note: Make sure to use node version > 5.1.0.